# Cython: cannot pass pointer on floating and floating memoryview

Tags: python, cython

The following example does not compile:

```
from cython cimport floating

cpdef int foo(floating * R, floating[:] theta):
    cdef int bar = 1
    return bar
```

Error:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
from cython cimport floating

cpdef int foo(floating * R, floating[:] theta):
             ^
------------------------------------------------------------

debug.pyx:3:14: Cannot convert Python object argument to type 'float *'

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
from cython cimport floating

cpdef int foo(floating * R, floating[:] theta):
             ^
------------------------------------------------------------

debug.pyx:3:14: Cannot convert Python object argument to type 'double *'
```

I can pass two pointers, two memoryviews, but not a combination. Is it normal ?

Comment: C pointers cannot be used in `def` or `cpdef` functions, how did you make it possible to pass two pointers? Maybe you  did it in a `cdef` function.

Comment: You're right, the two pointers were passed in a cdef function. Using cdef instead of cpdef fixed my issue.